# How to display warning message of invalid input div in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a new form in React, where I need to validate inputs and, in case of incorrect input, display alerts individually under each bad input.

What is the better solution?

1. Create a div in advance under each input and hide and show it with the help of classes.

```
<label htmlFor="first-name"></label>
<input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" />
<div className="invalid-input disable/enable">Please fill in your name.</div>
```

2. Create an auxiliary function that performs validation and then adds this warning div under each input.

```
const div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = "Please fill in your name.";

const input = document.getElementById("first-name");
insertAfter(div, input);
```

What is conventionally correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an error state as a boolean variable or object with errors for each field using useState.

```
const [error, setError] = useState(false)
```

Further display an error through such a record:

```
{error && <div>message error</div>}
```

If errors = false, then the message does not appear